# Is it bad to have a lot of forms in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a xlsxm file that I'm planning on adding about 15 forms to, possibly more in order to allow for more fluid user interaction with data and more personalized pre built text.

For instance  each button they press opens a form where they select from various different options and save, and then depending on the options selected a cell gets filled with pre-formatted text

How much would this impact performance and file size? The file already had possibly more than 1000 lines of code spread out through worksheets and 3 forms and about 12 modules

Comment: True XD I'm just wondering because it's going to take a considerable amount of work and I'm worried it might become overwhelming

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered how or where will the intended users access it? Will it be via online, like SharePoint or Confluence? Or will it be locally accessed? Accessing it via online with that amount of data will be an issue.

Next, with that amount of forms, have you tried using worksheets first for user interaction? Consider utilizing Excel's Conditional Formatting and Data Validation Features for data interaction and personalizing text. Also, you can still add Form Controls under Developer Menu to run your macros.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would use con format or validation for what I need I press X button and it gives me multiples options to select and depending on the options it spits out the text I need ex: press vegetables btn and opens form to select what kind of vegetables are they if they are cooked or not then on saving a cell gets filled with we need cooked onions (this is a example)

Comment: In that case, pursue with user forms however stress test it before rolling it out to intended users... Second option is to utilize worksheet (as an interactive dashboard) and use form controls to trigger macros. For example, create a button form control which when clicked, will reveal the options on this column/field and for users to choose items, they have to put 'x' mark beside the cell (or something). Additionally, with Data Validation feature you can create drop down buttons with a list of options.

Answer (score -1):

Adding more code to a workbook will slow down its loading. Normally, you wouldn't notice because at the time of loading a workbook you are patient and 2 seconds won't trouble you.

However, with 1000 lines of code already existing and 15 forms being added you might wish to consider transferring your code to an add-in for the purpose of better management separate from the data contained in the workbook. This would speed up loading of the workbook because the add-in gets loaded together with the Excel application rather than each workbook.

The way to proceed would be to add the 15 forms to your existing workbook and see if there is any effect you wish to complain about. If so, the same code would/should work in an add-in. Changes would only be required if your code refers to `ThisWorkbook` or fails to identify the workbook objects properly. However, problems can be avoided with foresight. Just make sure to identify objects uniquely, which is good programming practice in any case.

Comment: I have A lot of thisworkbook code and since I'm working in a highly secured environment there is very limited internet access and also working in virtual machines on vmware put together by people that would never install addins for "security reasons" lol so every day we get to work any installed addins would be gone your comment did help me get a better picture of code management though thanks!